# How do I assign a particular string from a user given character?

Tags: java, string, class, methods, character-encoding

Okay, so basically let's say I want the user to enter a character a-z in case sensitive. How do I take the conversion from my other class and output in my driver class?

Every character will have a different assigned string to form one entire string at the end.

One example maybe would be if the user enters, 'p' for their character it would assign, 'p' to the string, "\k\PD' just something like that and simple stuff such as "m" will equate to 7.

So, how could this be done with the conversion happening in the instance class and the assigning of the character in the driver class?

Here is some code on how I'm working.

Driver class

```
char c1 = userInput.next(".")charAt(0);
```

Instance class

```
switch (Character.toUpperCase(c1))
{

    case 'm':
          string encode = "7";
          System.out.print(encode);
          break;

}
```

I think creating encode as an object would work. However, I don't think that's a necessary thing to do and something as copied as that.

Comment: None of that case statement would run in the instance class, you are setting it to upercase, then checking if it's a lowercase "m".

Comment: i literally have no idea what you are asking...

Comment: If you want it to be case sensitive, why are you eliminating case by calling `toUpperCase()`?

Comment: *"I think creating encode as an object would work"* More like creating `encode()` as a *method* would be the answer, don't you think?

Answer (score 0):

No sure if this is what you are asking.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {            

    StringBuilder stringbuilder = new StringBuilder();

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
    String userInput = input.nextLine();

    for(int i = 0; i < userInput.length(); i++)
    {
        stringbuilder.append(characterEncode(userInput.charAt(i)));
    }
    System.out.println("Encoded String: " + stringbuilder.toString());
}


static String characterEncode(char a)
{
    switch(a)
    {
        case 'a':
            return "7";                
        case 'b':
            return "9";                
        case 'c':
            return "4";
        default:
            return "0";               
    }
}
```

output:

```
run:
Enter a string: abcde abc
Encoded String: 794000794
```